# KNOX RemoteControl APIs - JNIEXPORTs or example code?

Tags: android, samsung-knox

I am working with the (Samsung) KNOX library, specifically the RemoteControl APIs, to get a screen capture (See [APIs](https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/native/html/classandroid_1_1IRemoteDesktop.html)).

The problem is, I cannot find any examples or references for calling the APIs from a standard Android Java application.  I've searched online but can't find more information.  All the questions on the Samsung forums asking for these same details go unanswered.

Can anyone point me to a working KNOX RemoteControl and/or Screen Capture example or the JNIEXPORTs so I can import the functions myself?